# adding properties from one object to another

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have two objects with a similar structure -

```
    var locations = { 
        "regions": [{
        "name": "Asia Pacific",
        "handle": "asia-pacific",
        "iso_code": "",
        "iso_code_3": "",
        "countries": [{
            "name": "Republic of Korea",
            "iso_code": "kr",
            "iso_code_3": "kor"
          },{
            "name": "Japan",
            "iso_code": "jp",
            "iso_code_3": "jap"
          }
        ]
      }]
    }


    var additionalLocations = { 
        "regions": [{
        "name": "Asia Pacific",
        "handle": "asia-pacific",
        "iso_code": "",
        "iso_code_3": "",
        "countries": [{
            "name": "Malaysia",
            "iso_code": "my",
            "iso_code_3": "mys",
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
```

How can I the country, Malaysia, from the additionalLocations object to the locations object?

It should look like this -

```
   var locations = { 
        "regions": [{
        "name": "Asia Pacific",
        "handle": "asia-pacific",
        "iso_code": "",
        "iso_code_3": "",
        "countries": [{
            "name": "Republic of Korea",
            "iso_code": "kr",
            "iso_code_3": "kor"
          },{
            "name": "Japan",
            "iso_code": "jp",
            "iso_code_3": "jap"
          },{
            "name": "Malaysia",
            "iso_code": "my",
            "iso_code_3": "mys",
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
```

I'm hoping there's a nifty underscore method that will do it for me.

Comment: See http://underscorejs.org/#union and http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

Answer (score 0):

```
locations.regions[0].countries.push(additionalLocations.regions[0].countries[0])
```

If you want to do this for multiple locations in a loop you'll need a little bit more but for the case you posted this should work.